# Add the inserted id to the pivot table

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I have a `users`, `items`, `user_item` tables. I need to populate the `user_item` table with a `user_id` and `item_id` when a user is created.

so far, I have a basic registration function

```
public function register(Request $request) {
    $user = User::create([
        'name' => $request->name,
        'user_type' => $request->user_type,
        'email' => $request->email,
        'password' => bcrypt($request->password)
      ]);
      $token = auth()->login($user);

      return $this->respondWithToken($token);
}
```

So far it saves only to the `users` table ofcourse.
I've looked at some documentations on using `attach()`, however, I got stuck on this one..

In the `register` function, i added a $item array:

```
$item = Item::create([
    'user_id' => !!!!, -> How do I get the id of the inserted user
    'instrument_id' => $request->instrument_id
]);

$user->role()->attach($item)
```

Also, what is `role()`? is it a built-in laravel function?

Note that I haven't tried running this function since I got stuck on these problems. So I don't event know if it's gonna work.

Anyone help me on this one? I'm a laravel newbie and got really confused on the documentations.

Answer (score 1):

the method [create](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_create) return the model it self after loading it's attributes from db,
so when you want the user id just use `$user->id` after `create()` method.

for the default permission that shipped with laravel it is
[spatie/laravel-permission](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission)

and to assign role to a user you can use:

```
$user->assignRole('writer');  // just set role name
```